# jQuery Ajax Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, error-handling

Hi I am using laravel jQuery & ajax to return a JSON error as so:

```
error: function (jqXhr, json, errorThrown) {
    var errors = JSON.stringify(jqXhr.responseJSON);
     var errorsHtml= '';
      $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
         errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>'; 
       });
        toastr.error( errorsHtml , "Error " + jqXhr.status +': '+ errorThrown);
                        
     }
```

However I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '209' in {"errors"{"name":["A name is required"],"hours":["Please input a capacity in hours."],"start_date":["Please input a start date."],"end_date":["Please input an end date."]}}
```

Any ideas, if I use `.parse` instead of `.stringify` i get the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token j`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

### edit

```
var errors = JSON.stringify(jqXhr.responseJSON);
console.log('normal'+jqXhr.responseJSON);
console.log('stringify: '+errors);
normal[object Object]
 stringify: {"errors":{"name":["A name is required"],"hours":["Please input a capacity in hours."],"start_date":["Please input a start date."],"end_date":["Please input an end date."]}}
```

Comment: Use neither? `var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON.errors`

Comment: Problem in new line symbol - rmove it ant all works fine

Comment: @minitech that comes back undefined

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk i can see the error can you post a solution?

Comment: @g_9020 Show console.log(arguments) and response body ( from developers tools )

Comment: JSON.stringify - convert Object-to-string. You need string-to-object. use parse() method

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk if I do that it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token j.`

Comment: var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON.errors; // you have parsed object . Just get it's property - no need in convertion

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk comes back undefined

Comment: Can you share link? It should be an object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79910/discussion-between-vasiliy-vanchuk-and-g-9020).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var errorsHtml = '';
    $.each(jqXhr.responseJSON.errors, function(key, value) {
         errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>'; 
    });
    toastr.error(errorsHtml, "Error " + jqXhr.status +': '+ errorThrown);
}
```

`jqXhr.responseJSON` is the response already parsed into an object. The JSON you show in the edit will be an object with one property named "errors". You want to loop through the key/values of that property.